# moment.js time wrongly calculated

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using the following in moment.js to convert seconds to Days Hours Minutes Seconds format

`moment().startOf('year').seconds(1209600).format('DD HH:mm:ss')`

But instead of getting `14 00:00:00`, I am getting `15 00:00:00`

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing that a year starts on 1 January, and 1 + 14 = 15.

Comment: Are you looking for a `duration` of 14 days??  That is very different than being on the 14th day of January.

Comment: yes, actually duration is what i wanted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1209600 seconds is 14 days, so because the first day of the year is day `01 00:00:00`, if you add 14 days you get `15 00:00:00`.

You don't say exactly what you're trying to do, but what you're getting is the right answer for "what's the date/time for 1209600 seconds into the year."

Comment: okay...thanks for your response. Could you tell me the best way to modify the above script so this is handled?

Comment: Only add 13 days instead of 14 ;-)? Respectively, add 1 second less, so you end up on January 14th, 23:59:59.

Comment: i am not passing this value myself...a random value is retrieved from the system and converted into the required format...the value could be anything from 1 to 3000000

Comment: @hnvasa so then what difference does it make? The value is added and you get the answer. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to work with the concept of *duration*, but you're using the calendar to do it.  This isn't a good idea for several reasons.  As others pointed out, the calendar starts on the 1st, which is throwing you off. But also, you could have local time zone discontinuities affect your results, such as if your duration went far enough into the year to be caught by the spring-forward daylight saving time transition.

If you want to use Moment to work with durations, there is [a separate API for that](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

```
var d = moment.duration(1209600, 'seconds');

var h = d.hours();
var m = d.minutes();
var s = d.seconds();
```

There is currently not a `format` method built-in for durations, so you'd have to assemble these into a string yourself, applying zero-padding where necessary.  However, there is the [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) third-party plugin, which would let you do it like this:

```
moment.duration(1209600, 'seconds').format('DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moment().startOf('year');    // set to January 1st, 12:00 am this year
```

So, `startOf('year')` method set moment starting point to 1st January of current year from `12.00 AM`
, which is start of the day. and you are adding 14 days on top of that. But as the initial date started at 12.00 AM, its still a whole day `(ends at 11.50 PM)` which adds one additional day in final result.